# My own method to execute xPath with Xercesc

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, xerces

I use Xercesc library to parse XML's, but this library could execute only simple xPath's. I've written my own methot for execute xPath like this one:

> myProj/Parameters/Parameter[@Name="SomeName"]/Values/@DefaultValue

but when I run my program I have "myProj.exe has triggered breakpoint" and I see "_CrtIsValidHeapPointer" method definition when debugging. When I avoid using my method - everything is ok, so something has to be wrong with my code, but I have no idea what.

```
        string executeXPath(const char *A_xmlFile, string xPathh, shared_ptr<vector<string>> sectionSqlVector)
    {
        scoped_ptr<XercesDOMParser> parser(new XercesDOMParser());
        parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
        parser->setDoNamespaces(true);    // optional

        scoped_ptr<ErrorHandler> errHandler((ErrorHandler*) new HandlerBase());
        parser->setErrorHandler(errHandler.get());
        parser->parse(A_xmlFile);

        const XMLCh* xPath = XMLString::transcode(xPathh.c_str());
        int pos = XMLString::indexOf(xPath,'@');
        int pos2 = XMLString::indexOf(xPath,('='));
        XMLCh* attrName = new XMLCh;
        XMLString::subString(attrName,xPath,pos+1,pos2);

        pos = XMLString::indexOf(xPath,'@', pos+1);
        XMLCh* attr2name = new XMLCh;
        XMLString::subString(attr2name, xPath, pos+1, XMLString::stringLen(xPath));

        pos = XMLString::indexOf(xPath,'"');
        XMLCh* attribute = new XMLCh;
        XMLString::subString(attribute, xPath, pos+1, XMLString::indexOf(xPath,'"',pos+1));

        DOMNode* docRootNode;
        DOMDocument* doc;
        doc = parser->getDocument();
        docRootNode = doc->getDocumentElement();
        DOMElement* elementRoot = doc->getDocumentElement();
        DOMNodeList* nodeList = elementRoot->getElementsByTagName(L"Parameter");
        XMLSize_t d = nodeList->getLength();
        string valuee = "";
        for (XMLSize_t i = 0; i < d; i++)
        {
            DOMElement* tempElement = (DOMElement*)nodeList->item(i);
            if (tempElement->hasAttribute(attrName))
            {
                const XMLCh* tempChar = tempElement->getAttribute(attrName);
                if (XMLString::equals(attribute,tempChar))
                {
                    DOMNodeList* tempList2 = tempElement->getElementsByTagName(L"Values");
                    DOMElement* tempElement2 = (DOMElement*)tempList2->item(0);
                    const XMLCh* defValue = tempElement2->getAttribute(attr2name);
                    valuee = XMLString::transcode(defValue);
                    tempElement2->release();
                }
            }
            tempElement->release();
        }
        doc->release();
        elementRoot->release();
        docRootNode->release();
        XMLString::release(&attr2name);
        XMLString::release(&attrName);
        XMLString::release(&attribute);

        return valuee;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry i cannot help you. I also have no idea. But what you are implementing is quite valuable. It would be great if you can post the final working code. Others can benefit from it.

Comment: I've managed this problem on my  own and this method works fine - as I've expected. The problem was with memory allocation. But this method executes only XPath mentioned above. Do you think someone will use it and consider it as valuable? If so, where I should publish my code? Here? In comment? Sorry, I'm not experienced in sharing my own code ;)

Comment: Yea xerces have a real problem with XPath and your code can give idea to people on how to implement your own custom XPath solution. The best way would be to post your solution in the answers. But if you do not have rights to that then you can EDIT your question and post the solution in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out method which is working fine for my needs.

```
string executeXPath(xercesc::DOMDocument* doc, string xPathh)
{
    const XMLCh* xPath = XMLString::transcode(xPathh.c_str());
    int pos = XMLString::indexOf(xPath,'@');
    int pos2 = XMLString::indexOf(xPath,('='));
    XMLCh* attrName = (XMLCh*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*(pos2-pos));
    XMLString::subString(attrName,xPath,pos+1,pos2);
    pos = XMLString::indexOf(xPath,'@', pos+1);
    XMLCh* attrName2 = (XMLCh*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*(XMLString::stringLen(xPath)-pos));
    XMLString::subString(attrName2, xPath, pos+1, XMLString::stringLen(xPath));
    pos = XMLString::indexOf(xPath,'"');
    XMLCh* attribute = (XMLCh*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*(XMLString::indexOf(xPath,'"',pos+1)-pos));
    XMLString::subString(attribute, xPath, pos+1, XMLString::indexOf(xPath,'"',pos+1));
    DOMElement* elementRoot = doc->getDocumentElement();
    DOMNodeList* nodeList = elementRoot->getElementsByTagName(L"Parameter");
    XMLSize_t d = nodeList->getLength();
    string valuee = "";
    for (XMLSize_t i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        DOMElement* tempElement = (DOMElement*)nodeList->item(i);
        if (tempElement->hasAttribute(attrName))
        {
            const XMLCh* tempChar = tempElement->getAttribute(attrName);
            if (XMLString::equals(attribute,tempChar))
            {
                DOMNodeList* tempList2 = tempElement->getElementsByTagName(L"Values");
                DOMElement* tempElement2 = (DOMElement*)tempList2->item(0);
                const XMLCh* defValue = tempElement2->getAttribute(attrName2);
                valuee = XMLString::transcode(defValue);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    delete attrName2;
    delete attrName;
    delete attribute;
    return valuee;
}
```